# Installing NimEDIT on MacOS Catalina

Tags: osx, text-editor, ide, macos, macos-catalina

I would like to install NimEDIT on my Mac but I can't figure out how.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Cross-post to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321147/how-to-install-nimedit-on-macos-catalina